# how to define an indicator?

Tags: r, dataframe

there is a group called PERNO, each group if in row i col2=="a", I want to define an indicator which is 1 for row of i+1 to end of group  or until it gets to "a" again

```
      PERNO     col2      col3
        1         b         3
        1         d         3
        1         a         4
        1         d         5
        2         v         2
        2         a         3
        2         a         4
        2         x         4
        2         h         5
```

output

```
      PERNO     col2      col3     indicator
        1         b         3          0 
        1         d         3          0
        1         a         4          0
        1         d         5          1
        2         v         2          0
        2         a         3          0
        2         a         4          0
        2         x         4          1
        2         h         5          1
```

in first group the forth row is 1 because its next to row of col2==a

in second group the 2 last row also are one

Comment: can we modify your code for a case when 2 "a" follow each other in 2 repetitive row the second one get 1, ? same in the second PURP in my exampl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ave(d$col2 != "a", d$PERNO, FUN = function(x){
    with(rle(x), rep(replace(values, 1, 0), lengths))
})
#[1] 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can compare `row_number()` with last index where `col2 == "a"` in each group

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(PERNO) %>%
  mutate(indicator = as.integer(row_number() > max(which(col2 == "a"))))

#  PERNO col2   col3 indicator
#  <int> <fct> <int>     <int>
#1     1 b         3         0
#2     1 d         3         0
#3     1 a         4         0
#4     1 d         5         1
#5     2 v         2         0
#6     2 a         3         0
#7     2 a         4         0
#8     2 x         4         1
#9     2 h         5         1
```

To implement the same logic in base R, we can use `ave`

```
as.integer(with(df, ave(col2 == "a", PERNO, FUN = function(x) 
                   seq_along(x) > max(which(x)))))
#[1] 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1
```

and with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, indicator := as.integer(seq_len(.N) > max(which(col2 == "a"))), by = PERNO]
```

Comment: also can we modify your code for a case when 2 "a" follow each other in 2 repetitive row the second one get 1, ? same in the second PURP in my exampl

Comment: @hghg you can replace `max` with `min`, `df %>%
  group_by(PERNO) %>%
  mutate(indicator = as.integer(row_number() > min(which(col2 == "a"))))
`

Answer (score 1):

An attempt which I think should work:

```
ave(dat$col2=="a", dat$PERNO, FUN=function(x) cummax(x) & (!x) )
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

ave(dat$col2=="a", dat$PERNO, FUN=function(x) cummax(x) & (!x) ) + 0
#[1] 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1
```

In *data.table* something like:

```
dat[, ind := cummax(col2=="a") & col2 != "a", by=PERNO]
```

The logic is basically that the indicator should remain `0` until an `"a"` is found, at which point the `cum`ulative `max`imum increases to `1`, and will remain at `1` until the end of the group. Any further runs of `"a"` should cause the indicator to be set back to `0`, hence the need to exclude these values with `col2 != "a"` or `(!x)`.

Comment: can we modify your code for a case when 2 "a" follow each other in 2 repetitive row the second one get 1, ? same in the second PURP in my exampl

Answer (score 0):

We can use `which` with `tail`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(PERNO) %>%
    mutate(indicator = +(row_number() > tail(which(col2 == "a"), 1)))
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   PERNO [2]
#  PERNO col2   col3 indicator
#  <int> <chr> <int>     <int>
#1     1 b         3         0
#2     1 d         3         0
#3     1 a         4         0
#4     1 d         5         1
#5     2 v         2         0
#6     2 a         3         0
#7     2 a         4         0
#8     2 x         4         1
#9     2 h         5         1
```

---

Same logic in `base R`

```
df1$indicator <- with(df1, ave(col2 == "a", PERNO, FUN = function(x)
                seq_along(x) > tail(which(x== "a'), 1)))
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, indicator := +(seq_len(.N) > tail(which(col2 == "a"), 1)), PERNO]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(PERNO = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
    col2 = c("b", "d", "a", "d", "v", "a", "a", "x", "h"), col3 = c(3L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```